# Как правильно подключить внешний тектовый файл в программу, чтобы он сохранялся и мог быть изменен при публикации приложения?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, ресурсы

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно добавить  внешний текcтовый и xml файл в проект WPF C# -  Чтобы он был также при публикации в одном каталоге с exe файлом и при этом, мне нужно чтобы при изменении этих файлов, программа считывала их правильно.
Когда я делаю простое добавление файлов  через Добавить/Существующий элемент - а затем в коде

```c
 path = path + "rl.xml";

 using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)) {
   Resonator[] desRes_array = (Resonator[]) formatter.Deserialize(fs);

   ListResonators = desRes_array.ToList();
 }
```

программа запускается, но во время редактирования в WPF XAML выходит ошибка, со ссылкой на папку "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE" и говорит, что там доступ запрещен.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Свойства у файлов делал - Всегда копировать, Действия при сборке - пробовал все - Содержимое/Ресурс, внедренный ресурс...

Тогда я подключил файл как ресурс через Properties - Resources -
а затем в коде

```c
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(Properties.Resources.rl);
```

- так ошибок никаких не появляется, но и самого файла отдельно нет - он видимо как то внутрь программы вшился.

Как сделать добавление файла, чтоб он был вот рядом с exe, и чтобы при его редактировании в программе изменялись данные, которые  в себе хранит. У меня 2 файла, XML с двумя объектами моего класса, и второй файл это обычный txt в котором прописан IP адресс типа "192.168.10.1"

Читал, смотрел про все эти добавления файлов, ресурсов и тд, окончательно запутался иниче не понял(

Comment: `string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "rl.xml")`